# RunTime error when installing package on raspberry pi

Tags: python, raspberrypi

I am trying to install a package called imutils using the pip command on my raspberry pi, which I need to create my security camera. I am encountering the following error.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo pip install imutils
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==1.5.6', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 356, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2476, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2190, in load
    ['__name__'])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 74, in <module>
    from pip.vcs import git, mercurial, subversion, bazaar  # noqa
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/vcs/mercurial.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip.download import path_to_url
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 22, in <module>
    import requests, six
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/__init__.py", line 61, in <module>
    raise RuntimeError('Requests dependency \'urllib3\' must be version >= 1.21.1, < 1.22!')
RuntimeError: Requests dependency 'urllib3' must be version >= 1.21.1, < 1.22!
```

I am very new to all of this, and I apologise for such a nooby question. I initially tried updating urllib3, but that didn't work at all. Thank you to anyone who is able to provide some help.

Comment: What exactly is the error message you get when doing `sudo pip install --upgrade urllib3`?

Answer (score 1):

I just had this same issue. I was unable to install a version of urllib3 later than 1.9 through apt-get, and any instance trying to use pip resulted in the urllib3 error.

I fixed it through installing it manually from the github repository.

**$ git clone git://github.com/shazow/urllib3.git 

$ python setup.py install**

Another option, although unsafe, is to manually edit /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/__init__.py and replace line 53 with

**major, minor, patch = (1,22,0)**

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried using git to install it manually, but when I typed the first line I received this error.

"fatal: destination path 'urllib3' already exists and is not an empty directory."

I then edited the file, and I am now receiving a new error.

"    from urllib3.exceptions import DependencyWarning
ImportError: cannot import name DependencyWarning"

If you could provide further help I would really appreciate it

Comment: Decided it would be easier to re-install both pip  and urllib3. I uninstalled them both, and re-downloaded them both. I noticed however that it downloaded urllib3 (1.9.1-3) , which is strange, because I have only just updated the information from repositories using sudo apt-get update.

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered the same problem.  I followed the above directions for reinstalling urllib3 from Github.

I then got an error message about problems with requests.  So, I followed the same pattern for requests:

```
git clone git://github.com/requests/requests.git
cd requests
python setup.py install
```

That did the trick!